# Exception thrown from a WindowsFormsHost control in a modal dialog. How do I handle it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am making a custom OPC Client application in WPF to communicate with a Kepware server. One of the functions is to configure a tag, including setting it's host and server. Now I could do this manually with calls to the Kepware ClientAce API for searching for valid network hosts and valid servers on that host, but ClientAce includes a .dll that already provides a tree control the user can browse directly. However, this out of the box control is in Windows Forms.

So I have this WPF Window that I launch as Modal Dialog with ShowDialog(). Within this window is a WindowsFormsHost element that contains the aforementioned server browsing control. It's works pretty well for the most part, including providing an event to handle when the user has made a new selection in the tree control. That event has a boolean parameter that indicates if the new selection is a server. A good thing since that's the very thing I'm trying to keep track of here.

It also provides a "server has been double-clicked" event, which I handle and have decided to interpret as a shortcut to the user selecting that server as the one they want. (Otherwise, they have to click a separate button for the currently selected server which I stored based on the aforementioned selection event.)

All good so far....

...But! There is another functionality Kepware added (well actually there's a few, but I'm not worried about those at this point). The user has the ability from a context menu to delete a server from the tree. For some reason, this is throwing a null exception (though, it successfully deletes the server from the tree). This is a very bad thing for my purposes because...:

1. I don't have any idea what leads to this. There is no stack trace. There is no extra information. Just that something, somewhere in that control has thrown an unhandled exception that I must now deal with.
2. I can't remove the context menu item. There's another context menu item that I can set a property in the XAML to remove, but that one isn't throwing the exception. It's the one I can't remove that is.
3. There's a lovely event called "ContextMenuItemClicked". It'd be nice if I could handle that. I just go into my handler, put a try/catch around the logic, and ignore the null exception that has absolutely nothing to do with me and what I'm trying to accomplish. However, the universe is against me here, and has decided that this is a mouse-click event, which Windows Forms doesn't want to propogate. I've searched around and this seems to be a common issue with Windows Forms and WPF interop. Mouse-clicks just don't play nice with the interop services. I tried. I really did. But the handler I made just sits there unused. Odd thing is, while I can understand why I can handle the "SelectionChanged" event from this control, I'm curious as to what Kepware did to make the "ServerDoubleClick" event propogate up, and why they didn't decide to extend that same courtesy to the context menu click.

So there I am. With an exception that isn't my fault, that I don't care about, and I apparently can't prevent. I just want to throw it away and move on. However, it's in a modal dialog, and I need to have this exception handled before the method that called ShowDialog() and popped this window up in the first place. (I'll spare you the details as to why. This post is long-winded enough as it is.)

Is there a way I can either somehow propogate the mouse events up, or trap this exception somewhere in my window class so that it doesn't propagate up the stack into the calling method?

Comment: You can't fix or patch this problem, it happens in code that is not yours that is called by code that is not yours.  You need to contact the vendor for support.  Be sure to have a small repro project available that demonstrates the problem, they are liable to ignore you if you ask for help the way you did here.

Comment: Isn't there an option to trap unmanaged exceptions as well?

Comment: Hans, I was afraid that was going to be the route I have to take. Thanks for letting me know that I've done all I can. Fortunately, the head of engineering here has informed me that we do have a tech support agreement with Kepware, so I won't have to go through our customer to get tech support.

And I am aware that I will have to ask for help differently with them than I did here. Because ultimately, I'm asking them to fix their product. They don't need to know any details about what I'm trying to do. And I can reproduce the problem with one control on a simple WPF app window.